# How to use boost::bind with "this" pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-signals

The code below is outputting the following error :

```
error C2663: 'boost::signal0<R,Combiner,Group,GroupCompare,SlotFunction>::connect' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
        with
        [
            R=void,
            Combiner=boost::last_value<void>,
            Group=int,
            GroupCompare=std::less<int>,
            SlotFunction=boost::function<void (void)>
        ]
```

Here is the code :

```
RepositoryEditor::RepositoryEditor(const boost::signal<void ()>& scenarioHasChangedSignal, QWidget* parent)
    : QDialog(parent),
    m_pActionRemove(new QAction(this))
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    m_pActionRemove->setText("Remove");
    m_pActionRemove->setToolTip("Remove this device");

    connect(m_pActionRemove , SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(onActionRemoveClicked()));
    connect(ui.buttonBox, SIGNAL(clicked(QAbstractButton *)), this, SLOT(onButtonClicked(QAbstractButton *)));
    connect(ui.treeWidgetDevicesList, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(onItemSelectionChanged()));
    connect(this, SIGNAL(itemRemovedFromTree(const Events::VCS::PnPDevice &)), RepositoryManager::getInstance().getRepository(), SLOT(removeDevice(const Events::VCS::PnPDevice &)));
    connect(RepositoryManager::getInstance().getRepository(), SIGNAL(deviceAdded(const DeviceItem &)), this, SLOT(addItemInTree(const DeviceItem &)));
    connect(RepositoryManager::getInstance().getRepository(), SIGNAL(deviceUpdated(const DeviceItem &)), this, SLOT(updateItemInTree(const DeviceItem &)));

    scenarioHasChangedSignal.connect(boost::bind(&RepositoryEditor::updateAllRootItem, this));

    this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint);
    this->setAttribute( Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, true );

    initTreeView();
}

void RepositoryEditor::updateAllRootItem()
{
    int index = ui.treeWidgetDevicesList->topLevelItemCount();
    for (int i=0;i<index;i++) 
    {
        RootItem rootItem = (ui.treeWidgetDevicesList->topLevelItem(i))->data(0,Qt::UserRole).value<RootItem>();
        (ui.treeWidgetDevicesList->topLevelItem(i))->setText(0,"test");

    }
}
```

The question is : **How to use bind function with "this" pointer?**

thank you

Comment: What is the signature of `updateAllRootItem`?

Comment: @AndyProwl  `void updateRootItem()`

Comment: Is the code an exact copy of the code failing for you?

Comment: @AndyProwl updateRootItem() is not const qualified no.  If it needs to be const qualified, I might be in trouble, because updateRootItem change variables...

Comment: @peterphonic: No, it doesn't. I got confused and deleted my comment, sorry

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas No it is not.  I thought it will be easier to read.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Added the exact copy of the failling code

Comment: You take the signal by const reference yet you intend on connecting to it?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Well, that was it :$  Guess I am a little bit tired, end of the day, last day before vacation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `scenarioHasChangedSignal` is const, whereas `connect` is a non-const member function, which can not be called on a const object. Declare `scenarioHasChangedSignal` as non-const `boost::signal<void ()>&`.